# inline-block vs inline do not appear to share the same baseline

Tags: html, css

I have stuffed two elements on a single line: an inline element followed by an inline-block element. Despite having exactly the same vertical-align: baseline, they do not appear to line up properly on the line. They are offset by one pixel on my test browser

A reduced testcase:

```
<div>
  <span style="background-color: #f00;">&nbsp;</span>
  <div style="background-color: #f00; display: inline-block; height: 1em">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vupn9yk6/

Any idea on how to make both elements perfectly aligned vertically ?

Answer (score 0):

Span is not a block level element. you have to update your css like this.

HTML

```
 <div class="someclass">
 <span style="background-color: #f00;">&nbsp;</span>
 <div style="background-color: #000;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.someclass span, .someclass div{display:inline-block}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6txfrvx/). Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

**inline**
inline element is not taking height and width, it's height and with property auto,

**inline-block**
inline-block element is taking height and width, if you not define in your css, when you will change the property in (inline-block) then it's came same base line

Please check below image

[image]

Comment: I am not able send to u second image